# Unable to receive integer return value when calling Python function from C++

Tags: python, c++, python-3.x

I am calling a Python function from my C++ code. The Python function takes two numbers as input and returns the sum. I am unable to retrieve the sum value in C++ code. Below are code for both C++ and Python files.

C++ code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include "Python.h"

int main()
{
    Py_Initialize();

    PyRun_SimpleString("import sys; sys.path.insert(0, '/home/aakash/Desktop/code/testpc')");

    //Run a python function
    PyObject *pName, *pModule, *pFunc, *pArgs, *pValue;
    pName = PyUnicode_FromString((char*)"sample");
    pModule = PyImport_Import(pName);
    pFunc = PyObject_GetAttrString(pModule, (char*)"main2");
    
    // pArgs = PyTuple_Pack(1, PyUnicode_FromString((char*)"Greg"));
    pArgs = PyTuple_New(2);
    PyTuple_SetItem(pArgs, 0, PyLong_FromLong(5));
    PyTuple_SetItem(pArgs, 1, PyLong_FromLong(6));
    pValue = PyObject_CallObject(pFunc, pArgs);
    auto result = _PyUnicode_AsString(pValue);
    std::cout << result << std::endl;
    Py_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

Python code in `sample.py` file:

```
def main2(a, b):
    print("getting sum ")
    c = a + b
    return c
```

Getting error:- `TypeError: bad argument type for built-in operation`.
Request to help for other datatypes too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution by replacing `auto result = _PyUnicode_AsString(pValue);` with `int result = PyFloat_AsDouble(pValue);`. But I am not fully convinced as I needed an integer, but I had to use a function which looks to be meant for dealing with Float/Double. So, waiting for an accurate answer. Thanks!